# When I cite an author twice a long line is drawn instead of the name

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I create my bibliography using JabRef and include it via:

```
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha} 
\bibliography{foo}
```

When I have two different citations from the same author in the second citation a long line is drawn instead of the authors name. How can I fix this?

Comment: Any other solution, maintaining the \bibliographystyle????

Comment: the answer below solved my problem - so i didn't do anything else.. maybe you should re-ask this question with focus on not changing the \bibliographystyle

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The shortest answer is, use a different `\bibliographystyle`.  Using a 3em dash instead of a repeated author name is by design for that bibliography style (if you're curious how they do it, look at the definition and use of `bysame` and the `\bysame` macro in the `amsalpha.bst` file).  The `alpha` style, for example, does not use the 3em dash.