# Name of authors in the references is replaced by a dashed line

Tags: bibtex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it normal for BibTeX to replace similar author names with “------”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29381/is-it-normal-for-bibtex-to-replace-similar-author-names-with)

I am compiling a latex file and the some papers in the references section do not have the authors' name after compilation. Please see reference [7] in the image below. Its bibtex entry is as below

```
@book{Welford1968_Book,
Address = {London},
Author = {Alan Traviss Welford},
Publisher = {Methuen},
Title = {Fundamentals of Skill},
Year = {1968}}
```

[image]

does any body know why this happens?

Comment: Which bibliography style are you using? Are you using `natbib` or other relevant package? Some styles replace repeated name authors with dashes.

Comment: Does [When I cite an author twice a long line is drawn instead of the name](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46021/5764) solve your problem? Using `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`, that is.

Comment: Hi @GonzaloMedina , I am not using `natbib` and I am using `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`

Comment: @Werner Yes it seems that the problem was `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` thanks

Comment: @Mark you don't have to change the style; the link I provided above shows how to proceed to deactivate the "dashify" option with `IEEEtran`.

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate as the comment from @Mark suggest this is the case. Note that closing a question is not final. If you feel that this question is not a duplicate you can edit it to add more information, in which case it may be reopened.

Comment: I was using the IEEEtranBST.zip from the paperplaza website. I had the same problem and I only opened the IEEEtran.bst and changed the #1 to #0 for the default.is.dash.repeated.names and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is default behavior of bibTeX.  This question has already been answered here, where a (rather ad-hoc) method of getting around this behavior is described:

[Is it normal for BibTeX to replace similar author names with "------"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29381/is-it-normal-for-bibtex-to-replace-similar-author-names-with)

Personally I switched from bibTeX to amsrefs for handling bibliographic entries.  amsrefs is much more configurable than bibTeX.  Google amsrefs for more details if you are interested in this -- incidentally amsrefs has a built-in option to disable this "dashing same author name" behavior.

Comment: Author name substitution is dependent on the BibTeX style in use: it's not 'the default behaviour' of BibTeX. I'd say `amsrefs`, while interesting, has never really taken off, and most people would say `biblatex` is the 'way forward'.